# Broken GRUB after new Ubuntu 18 partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I am having a problem i just cannot fix, although I have been looking around for a solution for some time now.

I currently have a dual boot partition with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. A few weeks ago I ran out of space in the Ubuntu partition, and because of all the segmentation in SSD unit, I decided that the safest way was to delete the partition, repair Windows (in theory to get rid of Grub) and redo a new partition for a new Ubuntu with more space to play.

I didn't have any error through that process, but when re-configuring the dual boot, I just couldn't access the new Ubuntu, my BIOS only gave me access to a broken grub from the old Ubuntu. I now can access that Ubuntu partition, but in the menu when loading the computer (f11) is indicated as the following:

> ```
>  PLEASE SELECT BOOT DEVICE:
> ```
>
> Windows Boot Manager (PNY CS3030 250GB SSD)
>
> ubuntu (PNY CS3030 250GB SSD)
>
> SATA1: ST9250827AS
>
> SATA2: WDC ED10EZEX-60WN4A1
>
> **PNY CS3030 250GB SSD  (this is the new working ubuntu)**
>
> Enter Setup

If I press the second option (Ubuntu (SSD)) I land in a broken grub window exactly like [this one](https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Ubuntu-Grub-Console.png), and if I press the third option I able to enter my current Ubuntu SO and work normally. I have tried to get rid of the second option, redoing again all the process of uninstalling Ubuntu, repairing Windows etc but at the end, this is the best I could do.

I tried to figure out what was happening, and I suppose that the grub is pointing at a wrong direction. I don't know a lot, I have kept with this because I am in the middle of a coding bootcamp and time is limited, but I believe that this is causing the computer to freeze from time to time, which never happened before and it is beginning to worry me a bit to have to keep this way until the bootcamp finishes.

I have tried `sudo update-grub` and it gives me the following error:

```
(base) lucia@lucia-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] contraseña para lucia: 
Obteniendo el archivo «/etc/default/grub»
Obteniendo el archivo «/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg»
Generando un fichero de configuración de grub...
Encontrada imagen de linux: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Encontrada imagen de memoria inicial: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Encontrada imagen de linux: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Encontrada imagen de memoria inicial: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
error: invalid volume.
hecho
```

**EDIT**

After running `sudo efibootmgr` this is what I get:

```
(base) lucia@lucia-ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact output including the error from update-grub.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text from the terminal. Always copy the output directly from the terminal and paste it directly in the question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: It looks like you may have an old item in the EFI System partition (ESP). Please add the output of the command `sudo efibootmgr` in your question. This may tell us if the invalid Ubuntu partition is coming from there.

Comment: So this is not what I thought to be the problem.

Comment: Some googling says that `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg` is obsolete  - it does not exist on my 18.04 system. I would examine that file and see if it references your old partition.

Comment: I still don't know what is going on. But it looks like Windows is installed in UEFI and Ubuntu in Legacy mode. The "Please Select Boot Device" menu is part of the UEFI/Boot process. The extra menu item there is provided by UEFI/BIOS. If this is the case, it has nothing to do with grub or Ubuntu. This is just a guess.